# Re-balancing consumer is re-reading, causing old messages to re-enter the stream

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using kafka to stream messages between two microservices, but having an issue resolving this one "error". I have auto commit enabled and when I receive this error:

```
kafka.errors.CommitFailedError: CommitFailedError: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already 
rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls 
to poll() was longer than the configured max_poll_interval_ms, which typically implies that the poll loop 
is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the rebalance 
timeout with max_poll_interval_ms, or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with 
max_poll_records.
```

This is my understanding from this error message. The auto commit failed so the consumer offset did not update, the next time a new message is sent it will also send the previous messages (starting from offset) causing the duplicate message. Is that correct?

I tried to play around with the `max_poll_interval_ms` and `max_poll_records` values but it didn't help. I very much could be setting them to the incorrect values. Should I set the `auto_offset_reset` to `latest`?

There are a few parameters that are commented out because those configurations did not solve the issue. This is currently what I have running:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
                bootstrap_servers=[
                    ...
                ],
                auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                enable_auto_commit=True,
                group_id='my-client',
                # max_poll_records=1,
                # max_poll_interval_ms=5000,
                # heartbeat_interval_ms=1000,
                # session_timeout_ms=5000,
                api_version=(2, 2, 1))
```

Update

When I print out the ConsumerRecord, the offset seems to be incrementing fine

```
ConsumerRecord(topic='data-topic-one', partition=0, offset=62, timestamp=1601451089085, timestamp_type=0, key=None, value=b'{"val": 1})
...
...
ConsumerRecord(topic='data-topic-one', partition=0, offset=63, timestamp=1601451089085, timestamp_type=0, key=None, value=b'{"val": 2})
...
...
ConsumerRecord(topic='data-topic-one', partition=0, offset=64, timestamp=1601451089085, timestamp_type=0, key=None, value=b'{"val": 3})
```

After processing and saving the records in my database I end up with

First insert result

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "value": [
       {
            "val": 1
       }
    ]
}
```

Second insert result

```
{
    "id": "456",
    "value": [
       {
            "val": 1
       },
       {
            "val": 2
       }
    ]
}
```

Third insert result

```
{
    "id": "789",
    "value": [
       {
            "val": 1
       },
       {
            "val": 2
       },
       {
            "val": 3
       }
    ]
}
```

The expected result should be

First insert result

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "value": [
       {
            "val": 1
       }
    ]
}
```

Second insert result

```
{
    "id": "456",
    "value": [
       {
            "val": 2
       }
    ]
}
```

Third insert result

```
{
    "id": "789",
    "value": [
       {
            "val": 3
       }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This post might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60924842/kafka-consumer-commitfailedexception

Comment: That makes sense, but having a hard time figuring out the right values to use. If I use max_poll_records should I also change the  max_poll_interval_ms and heartbeat_interval_ms?

Comment: Could changing auto_offset_reset to latest help as well?

Comment: setting the auto_auto_offset to latest is only postponing the issue I guess :)

Comment: That's true - I'll play around with the values, but just touching base on all possible solutions, what if I disabled auto commit and instead committed the offset when I finished processing the data?

Comment: Seems like the right way going forward, however does it ensure at least one delivery?

Comment: Do you know the best way to test out the new poll records, intervals, etc.?

Comment: When you comment these params, check are they falling back to default values?                # heartbeat_interval_ms=1000,
    # session_timeout_ms=5000,

Comment: I started using these values, but sometimes it still throws the error - max_poll_records=1,
max_poll_interval_ms=180000,
heartbeat_interval_ms=20000,
session_timeout_ms=60000,

Comment: When I receive the message I print the ConsumerRecord and the offset seems to be incrementing correctly and the payload has the exact record, but for some reason when I insert it into the database I still see all the previous records coupled with it. I updated the question to reflect this comment

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been asked another time by the same user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64142881/kafka-offset-is-committed-but-still-receiving-duplicate-messages

Comment: I've removed the other post

Comment: Any tips on debugging this? I've tried adjusting the values but still not luck. The offsets are updating but I am getting old messages. At one point the consumer just stops receiving messages.