# Kafka commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm struggling with this failure:
`Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member` when I manually commit offsets within my Kafka consumer.

I have a child thread that does the actual processing while the parent thread sends heartbeats to the cluster on 3 second intervals.

- max.poll.interval.ms is default (5 minutes)
- max.poll.records is default (500 records)

Record size is small and the poll is large. Also, given that I'm running processing in child thread with async heartbeats, I feel I should run into this issue.

Just to be extra safe.. I only commit offsets on the partitions I own via `consumer.assignment()`. How is it possible that I'm still plagued with this error? I've tried many different things and can't come to a viable solution, leading to many duplicate records being processed.

Comment: Can you show the code how you have implemented this: "I have a child thread that does the actual processing while the parent thread sends heartbeats to the cluster on 3 second intervals."

Comment: Maybe the answer in this post can help: [Kafka Consumer CommitFailedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60924842/kafka-consumer-commitfailedexception)