# Impact of max.poll.records on the network call being made between consumer and broker

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Kafka [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_max.poll.records) of `max.poll.records` states

> The maximum number of records returned in a single call to `poll()`.
> Note, that `max.poll.records` does not impact the underlying fetching
> behavior. The consumer will cache the records from each fetch request
> and returns them incrementally from each poll.

In many places (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64368444/785523)) it is stated that setting `max.poll.records` to some high value reduces the network calls being made to the broker. Can someone explain to me how setting `max.poll.records` to some higher value(e.g. the default 500) as opposed to 1 may reduce the network calls being made if the fetching behaviour is independent of this setting?

If the processing code in a consumer is processing each record one after another (to maintain the ordering guarantee of all records in a partition), does it even have any advantage of setting the value of `max.poll.records` to something higher than 1?

Comment: If set to one, then you need to make 500 calls vs just one call, by default. Where's the confusion? You'll also have to set other fetch bytes sizes, yes

Comment: What calls you are referring to? I am asking about the network calls. Haruk's answer confirms what I was thinking. Having poll.records to 1 will not always make 500 fetch calls. It will depend on record size and fetch.bytes configured. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: TCP network calls. The Kafka documentation has a section on the protocol. As mentioned, you'll also need to set fetch configurations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kafka documentation is correct. `max.poll.records` doesn't affect the frequency of network calls.

In a nutshell, KafkaConsumer's poll works like below ([refs](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.6.1/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.java#L1186-L1204)):

- 1. collect records from internal buffer up to `max.poll.records`
- 2. send next fetches for partitions which have no in-flight request and no pending records remained
- 3. return collected records

Regardless we set `max.poll.records` to high or low, fetch requests are sent only when previously-fetched records are processed.