# max poll interval and session timeout ms | kafka consumer alive

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

**Scenario:**

Committing offsets manually after processing the messages.

session.timeout.ms: 10 seconds

max.poll.interval.ms: 5 minutes

Processing of messages consumed in a "poll()" is taking 6 minutes

**Timeline:**

A (0 seconds): app starts poll(), have consumed the messages and started processing (will take 6 minutes)

B (3 seconds): a heartbeat is sent

C (6 seconds): another heartbeat is sent

D (5 minutes): another heartbeat is sent (5 * 60 % 3 = 0) BUT "max.poll.interval.ms" (5 minutes) is reached

At point "D" will consumer:

1. send "LeaveGroup request" to consider this consumer "dead" and re-balance?
2. continue sending heartbeats every 3 seconds ?

If point "1" is the case, then

a. how will this consumer commit offsets after completing the processing of 6 minutes considering that its partition(s) are changed due to re-balancing at point "D" ?

b. should the "max.poll.interval.ms" be set in prior according to the expected processing time ?

If point "2" is the case, then will we never know if the processing is actually blocked ?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Kafka version 0.10.1.0, consumer heartbeats are sent in a background thread, such that the client processing time can be longer then the session timeout without causing the consumer to be considered dead.

However, the `max.poll.interval.ms` still sets the maximum allowable time for a consumer to call the `poll` method.

In your case, with a processing time of 6 minutes it would mean at point "d" that your consumer will be considered dead.

Your concerns are right, as the consumer will then *not* be able to commit the messages after 6 minutes. Your consumer will get a CommitFailedExcpetion (as described in another anser on [CommitFailedExcpetion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60924842/kafka-consumer-commitfailedexception/60925531#60925531).

To conclude, yes, you need to increase the `max.poll.interval.ms` time if you already know that your processing time will exceed the default time of 5 minutes.

Another option would be to limit the fetched records during a `poll` by decreasing the configuration `max.poll.records` which defaults to 500 and is described as: "The maximum number of records returned in a single call to poll()".