# spring-kafka | consumers are stopping eventually with CommitFailedException in spring-kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

We are facing an issue with spring-kafka, When we start a consumer application it works well for few days and it starts rebalancing and starts getting below errors in a specific time interval. Consumer joins back the group for few times, but it fails to join the group at one point. And eventually, we lose consumers one by one in few hours. So Kafka will not have consumers listening on the topic. Spring application still runs but all the Kafka consumers are stopped.

**We can see the following error/info logs multiple times:**

```
2021-May-05 20:06:50:062 PM [xxx_consumer_group-0-C-1] ERROR o.s.k.l.BatchLoggingErrorHandler - Error while processing: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Offset commit cannot be completed since the consumer is not part of an active group for auto partition assignment; it is likely that the consumer was kicked out of the group.
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.sendOffsetCommitRequest(ConsumerCoordinator.java:1134)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsSync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:999)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1504)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doCommitSync(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2396)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.commitSync(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2391)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.commitIfNecessary(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2377)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.processCommits(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2191)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1149)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1075)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

2021-May-05 20:07:11:662 PM [xxx_consumer_group-0-C-1] ERROR o.s.k.l.BatchLoggingErrorHandler - Error while processing: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator$OffsetCommitResponseHandler.handle(ConsumerCoordinator.java:1251)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator$OffsetCommitResponseHandler.handle(ConsumerCoordinator.java:1158)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:1132)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:1107)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:206)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:169)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:129)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.fireCompletion(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:602)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.firePendingCompletedRequests(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:412)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:297)

INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx_consumer_group-4, groupId=xxx_events_consumer_group] Group coordinator x.x.x.x:9092 (id: 2147483645 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery

INFO o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx_events_consumer_group-5, groupId=xxx_events_consumer_group] SyncGroup with Generation{generationId=104, memberId='consumer-xxx_events_consumer_group-5-397bbf1b-c09b-4b0c-91cc-94b62a23a51f', protocol='range'} failed: The coordinator is not aware of this member., would request re-join

INFO o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx_events_consumer_group-5, groupId=xxx_events_consumer_group] Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownMemberIdException: The coordinator is not aware of this member.

INFO o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx_events_consumer_group-5, groupId=xxx_events_consumer_group] (Re-)joining group

INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx_events_consumer_group-5, groupId=xxx_events_consumer_group] Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.MemberIdRequiredException: The group member needs to have a valid member id before actually entering a consumer group.

INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx_events_consumer_group-5, groupId=xxx_events_consumer_group] (Re-)joining group
```

This works well in a dev environment, we see these errors and the consumer always joins back the consumer group. But we are facing this issue in the production environment repeatedly. Production has more load on the consumers as compared with dev.

If consumers are down and if we restart it, we start getting this error in 15-20 mins and we start losing consumers. If we clean the zookeeper and Kafka logs and restarts the consumers, then it works well for 2-3 days. We tried reducing `max.poll.records` to less and increasing `max.poll.interval.ms` time but still facing the same issue.

**Below are the consumer properties and code snippets:**

**Versions :**
Spring boot - 2.4.3 / Kafka - kafka_2.13-2.6.0

**Kafka consumer factory / application properties:**

```
KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, MessageEvent>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(KafkaProperties properties) {
  Map<String, Object> props = properties.buildConsumerProperties();
  ConsumerFactory<String, MessageEvent> consumerFactory =  new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
  ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MessageEvent> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
  factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
  factory.setConcurrency(1);
  factory.setBatchListener(true);
  factory.setBatchErrorHandler(new BatchLoggingErrorHandler());
  return factory;
}

spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=xxxx:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=com.xxx.EventDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records=10
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.interval.ms=900000
```

**Sample consumer code:** (we have 6 such methods to create different types of kafka consumers in one component)

```
@KafkaListener(id = "${kafka.group.name}", topics = "${kafka.topic.name}", groupId = "${kafka.group.name}")
public void receiveMessages(@Payload List<ConsumerRecord<String, EventTYpe>> records) {
    process(records); // this submits all the records to ThreadPoolTaskExecutor to process in parallel.
}
```

**Kafka Consumer Properties:**

```
2021-May-05 04:08:59:992 AM [main] INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.ConsumerConfig - ConsumerConfig values:
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [xxxx:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = xxx_events_consumer_group-1
    client.rack =
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = xxx_consumer_group
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 900000
    max.poll.records = 10
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    value.deserializer = class com.xxx.EventDeserializer
```

Please suggest, if we are doing something in the wrong way or any leads would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are passing the records off to another thread (which is dangerous, by the way - you could lose data); I don't see how it's possible to trigger a rebalance due to Kafka thinking the consumer is dead. Something else is going on.

Comment: We are doing heavy processing in consumer, so we pass it to executor pool and wait on a future until all the records are completed. What is the recommend way to do heavy processing in spring kafka consumer to achieve parallel processing. What could be happening in above scenario, we tried multiple ways but could not be able ro fix it.

Comment: OK; it's ok as long as you wait for a future. You need to reduce the batch size and/or increase the `max.poll.interval.ms`. There is no other solution.

Comment: Sure, will try this. Thanks Gary for quick help. Really appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kafka Consumer CommitFailedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60924842/kafka-consumer-commitfailedexception)

Comment: No @mike, Kakfa consumer rejoins the group and process messages even after failing with CommitFailedException right ? We are sill facing this issue, We tried reducing batch size and increasing `max.poll.interval.ms`.